# Determine file being used by FileHandler

Tags: java, logging

I am creating a `java.util.logging.FileHandler` that is allowed to cycle through files. When multiple instances of my application are run, a new log file is created for each instance of the application. I need to know what file is being used by the application because I want to upload the log file to my servers for further review. How can I tell what file is being used by a certain FileHandler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to put some kind of identifier in the file name itself, i.e. the `pattern` argument when you create the FileHandler.  Since these are instances of the same application, one way to distinguish them is by their process id, so you could make that part of the pattern.  A better approach is to pass in an identifier through the command line and use that to make your filename.  That way you control the files being created in some sense.  Finally, if your application has some knowledge of why it's different from all the others, for example it connects to a particular database server, then you could just use that database server name as part of the filename.

EDIT:  There does not seem to be any API to get the name of the file being used by a FileHandler.  I would suggest looking into the logging extensions in x4juli (which ports a lot of the log4j functionality to the java.util.logging specs):

- http://www.x4juli.org/

You should be able to substitute an instance of their FileHandler which provides a getFile() method:

- http://www.x4juli.org/api/org/x4juli/handlers/FileHandler.html

Comment: Well, every time a new instance is run, the log file is incremented as so:
1st instance - log.0
2nd instance - log.1
3rd instance - log.2

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood your question.  It seems you can already associate an instance with a file - what else do you need?  If you need further identifying information, like what does instance 1, 2, or 3 mean, then you need to enhance it in the way I've specified above.  If not, then please clarify.

Comment: Lets say I have 3 instances running, and each has its own log file, as stated in my last comment. Instance 2 encounters an error, and logs the error to its logfile (log.1), it will then need to upload the logfile to a server, but in order to upload it, it must know which logfile it just wrote to, which will be same one it will upload.

Comment: Thank you, the library you referred me to allowed me to use the same logfile for multiple instances, which doesn't require me to find the logfile anymore, which is even better. :)

Comment: Sadly, x4juli.org no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you could do this much simpler by simply extending FileHandler yourself. For example...

MyFileHandler.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
public class MyFileHandler extends FileHandler {
    protected String _MyFileHandler_Patern;
    public MyFileHandler(String pattern) throws IOException {
        _MyFileHandler_Patern = pattern;
    }
    public String getMyFileHandlerPattern() {
        return _MyFileHandler_Patern;
    }
}
```

DeleteMe.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class DeleteMe {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DeleteMe.class.getName());
        MyFileHandler output = new MyFileHandler("output.log");
        log.addHandler(output);
        for (Handler handler : log.getHandlers()) {
            if (handler instanceof MyFileHandler) {
                MyFileHandler x = (MyFileHandler) handler;
                if ("output.log".equals(x.getMyFileHandlerPattern())) {
                    System.out.println("found hanlder writing to output.log");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is if you used patterns how do you know the real file that is begin used?

Comment: You also need to add a call to super(pattern) in the controller MyFileHandler, else the file is not being used to write the logs.
Excellent approach, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I do have to say that FileHandler not providing a way to determine the log file is seriously dumb.

I wound up writing a function called "chooseFile()" which searches /tmp for the next available log file name and returns that file.  You can then pass the name of that file into new FileHandler().

```
/**
 * Utility: select a log file.  File is created immediately to reserve
 * its name.
 */
static public File chooseFile(final String basename) throws IOException {
    final int nameLen = basename.length();
    File tmpDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
    String[] logs = tmpDir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File d, String f) { 
            return f.startsWith(basename);
        }
    });
    int count = 0;
    if (logs.length > 0) {
        for (String name : logs) {
            int n = atoi(name.substring(nameLen));
            if (n >= count) count = n + 1;
        }
    }
    String filename = String.format("%s%d.log", basename, count); 
    File logFile = new File(tmpDir, filename);
    logFile.createNewFile();
    return logFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my rather hacky way around it. It works for the default if you don't use any format strings, and should work if you use the g and u format strings in filename, but not the others.

```
public class FriendlyFileHandler extends FileHandler {

    /***
     * In order to ensure the most recent log file is the file this one owns,
     * we flush before checking the directory for most recent file.
     * 
     * But we must keep other log handlers from flushing in between and making
     * a NEW recent file.
     */
    private static Object[] flushLock = new Object[0];

    private String pattern;

    public FriendlyFileHandler(String pattern, int maxLogLengthInBytes, int count) throws IOException,
            SecurityException {
        super(pattern, maxLogLengthInBytes, count);

        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    /***
     * Finds the most recent log file matching the pattern.
     * This is just a guess - if you have a complicated pattern 
     * format it may not work.
     * 
     * IMPORTANT: This log file is still in use. You must 
     * removeHandler() on the logger first, .close() this handler, 
     * then add a NEW handler to your logger. THEN, you can read 
     * the file. 
     * 
     * Currently supported format strings: g, u
     * 
     * @return A File of the current log file, or null on error.
     */
    public synchronized File getCurrentLogFile() {

        synchronized(flushLock) {

            // so the file has the most recent date on it.
            flush();


            final String patternRegex =
                    // handle incremental number formats
                    pattern.replaceAll("%[gu]", "\\d*") +
                    // handle default case where %g is appended to end
                    "(\\.\\d*)?$";

            final Pattern re = Pattern.compile(patternRegex);
            final Matcher matcher = re.matcher("");

            // check all files in the directory where this log would be
            final File basedir = new File(pattern).getParentFile();
            final File[] logs = basedir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

                @Override
                public boolean accept(final File pathname) {
                    // only get files that are part of the pattern
                    matcher.reset(pathname.getAbsolutePath());

                    return matcher.find();
                }

            });

            return findMostRecentLog(logs);
        }
    }

    private File findMostRecentLog(File[] logs) {

        if (logs.length > 0) {
            long mostRecentDate = 0;
            int mostRecentIdx = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < logs.length; i++) {
                final long d = logs[i].lastModified();

                if (d >= mostRecentDate) {
                    mostRecentDate = d;
                    mostRecentIdx = i;
                }

            }

            return logs[mostRecentIdx];
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public synchronized void flush() {

        // only let one Handler flush at a time.
        synchronized(flushLock) {
            super.flush();
        }
    }

}
```